# Any reason why a DMG file throws a checksum error on open?

Tags: high-sierra, install

OK, so I have a vendor-supplied DMG (Steinberg) containing an installer package. The vendor insists the file is fine. They are testing the installer on Mojave. My system is High Sierra.

The DMG archive has been downloaded separately twice and both downloads are identical.

When opening the DMG under High Sierra 10.3.6 the diskMounter throws a checksum error and refuses to open the DMG.

Is there any reason why a DMG that is prepared on Mojave will not open under High Sierra when it opens fine under Mojave?

Comment: I have, from time to time, had issues with damaged downloads. Usually switching to another web browser, rebooting the router did it for me.  But a checksum is a checksum and the version of the OS does not matter as the checksum is inherent in the *file* not the OS.

Comment: Did you check against Steinberg's published checksum? If it's a publicly-downloadable link I can check here on El Cap, High Sierra & Mojave to see if I can repro.

Comment: https://www.steinberg.net/sda-mac Can you check on both High Sierra and Mojave for me? filename is Steinberg_Download_assistant_1.16.2_Installer_mac.dmg and the MD5 is d887dc96dba590cf7e72bcb2f463686d

Comment: Opens fine on all 3 Macs. Checksums don't match yours though - I get 89bdd380c42491a52921d0f3808f5d83 I would suspect bad download; probably a cached copy if you're getting the same each time. Try another machine, another browser, another connection etc

Comment: All good mate - I will try again here.

Comment: Tried again tonight on both Chrome and Firefox. I still get exactly the same file with the same md5 checksum. Something tells me that their CDN is awry.

Comment: Hmm..possibly. I'm UK, London, Steinberg is Hamburg, but of course these days that tells us nothing as to where their distribution goes & idk which CDN structure they use either. Trying to traceroute it gets caught up in Barefruit shenanigans, so that tells me nothing. I'd give Steinberg a shout & ask them. idk what their end-user support is like but the upper echelons are fabulous, I've known them for decades. Give support a try. If you get stonewalled, let me know. I could always drop you the file via wetransfer or similar, but I'm sure it would be better to get SB to fix it.

Comment: I have tried again using a separate computer, OS and Network in another city, and I am getting a file which has the same MD5 as you, which I assume is the correct one. Starting to feel like CDN.